# get the distribution function

Tags: probability, functional-analysis

I have the following density function:
$ f(x) = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    cx^2+|x| & \quad \text{if -1/2<x<1/2}\\
    0 & \quad \text{otherwise}
  \end{array} \right.$

we know that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{f(x)dx = 1}=\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}{cx^2+|x|dx = 1}$ and I get $c=9$.

The distribution function should be:
$ F(x) = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    3x^3-x^2/2 & \quad \text{if -1/2<x<0}\\
    3x^3+x^2/2 & \quad \text{if 0 <= x<1/2}\\
    0 & \quad \text{otherwise}
  \end{array} \right.$

If i want to test if $F(x)->1, \text{as} \space x->\infty$ it is not $1$, is the distribution function right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cdf is not right. We will use the fact that 
$$F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)\,dt,$$
where $f(t)$ is the density function.

Thus $F(x)=0$ for $x\lt -\frac{1}{2}$.

For $-\frac{1}{2}\le x\le 0$, we have
$$F(x)=\int_{-1/2}^x (9t^2-t)\,dt.$$
The antiderivative was computed correctly, but the substitution of endpoints was not. Once you compute an antiderivative $G(t)$, you need to find $G(x)-G(-1/2)$. You should end up with $\frac{1}{2}$ more than what you actually got.

For $0\lt x\le \frac{1}{2}$, 
$$F(x)=\frac{1}{2}+\int_0^x (9t^2+t)\,dt.$$
Finally, $F(x)=1$ for $x\gt \frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your distribution function is not correct. It should be
$$
F(x) = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
0,\quad &x<-\frac{1}{2}\\
3x^3-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \quad &-\frac{1}{2}<x<0\\
    3x^3+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2} & \quad 0 \le x < \frac{1}{2}\\
    1 & \quad \frac{1}{2}\le x
  \end{array} \right.
$$